Ag Grid Community Version v32.0.0 breaks if filter = true
I am using AG Grid Community in JavaScript. After upgrading to AG Grid v32.0.0, my grid is stuck in the loading phase.

In the console, I encounter the following error:
ag-grid-community.min.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')
    at new ja (ag-grid-community.min.js:1:158462)
    at Ya.setupTap (ag-grid-community.min.js:1:165815)
    at Ya.init (ag-grid-community.min.js:1:164833)
    at e.initComponent (ag-grid-community.min.js:1:199215)
    at e.newAgStackInstance (ag-grid-community.min.js:1:198867)
    at Object.newAgStackInstance (ag-grid-community.min.js:1:198231)
    at Dr.setUserCompDetails (ag-grid-community.min.js:1:359984)
    at Object.setUserCompDetails (ag-grid-community.min.js:1:359462)
    at Kr.setCompDetails (ag-grid-community.min.js:1:387768)
    at Kr.setupUserComp (ag-grid-community.min.js:1:387699)

After investigating, I discovered that if the filter property in gridOptions is set to anything other than false, the grid fails to load. Reverting to the previous version of AG Grid resolves the issue:
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ag-grid-community@31.3.2/dist/ag-grid-community.min.js"></script>
It seems that the new version introduced a bug related to filters. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Is there anything in the release notes or the upgrade docs

I couldn't find any information on how to set the filters differently in version 32 release notes.
Usually, when Ag Grid changes the configuration methods, they provide warnings before the release. This happened, for instance, when the Grid initialization was converted to a constructor. However, this time there was no warning.

I faced a similar issue, following an upgrade to version 32.
In my case, I was using a custom header component, which was in the old format, so it was missing the "eFilterButton" element as shown in the link below, so you may need to add that if you are using a custom header component:
https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/column-headers/#provided-component
<span data-ref="eFilterButton" class="ag-header-icon ag-header-cell-filter-button" aria-hidden="true"></span>

Also, my custom component was using "ref" attribute, which had to be updated to "data-ref" to render the column headers correctly.
Version 32 also uses the "new" column menu by default which requires this element to be present if filters are enabled and as it was not defined in my custom component it had an error when loading the grid.
I actually changed by grid to use columnMenu "legacy" via the gridApi as I did not want the filter button to be shown and hidden in the menu.
E.g,
<ag-grid-angular 

..... other bindings/events etc ......

[columnMenu]="gridConfiguration.columnMenu"

</ag-grid-angular>

where gridConfiguration.columnMenu is a internal settings object in my codebase.

Please submit this issue on the AG Grid GitHub issues page.
As part of your submission provide a live example reproducing this issue built on plunker/stackblitz/codesandbox and a list of steps to reproduce the issue.

Thank you very much all, for your answers.
In my case I found the issue.
You can locate a grid that is correctly configured with filters here
In my case I had configured the defaultColDef as follows:
defaultColDef: {filter: True}

This is not valid in version 32.
Instead, you will need to explicitly set the filter according to the data type of each column
const columnDefs = [
  { field: "text", filter: "agSetColumnFilter" },
  { field: "number", filter: "agNumberColumnFilter" },
  { field: "date", filter: "agDateColumnFilter" },
  { field: "choices", filter: "agMultiColumnFilter" }, # Enterprise
  { field: "no filter", filter: false },
]

